# Component Re-rendered from State Change But No Effect on DOM

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a Comments component in React with the Add Comment form as a child component. The Comments component has a `hasNewComment` state which is successfully updated by the child Add Comment form, via a callback function `handleNewComment` passed down as a prop. I can see the state is updated upon form submit in the child (console.log under render() shows `hasNewComment` is toggled to true), however the comment list does not refresh. I was under the impression that any state change would trigger re-rendering.

This is created with create-react-app. I have tried moving the child component into the parent but got the same result.

```
//PARENT

class Comments extends React.Component {

  state = {
    hasComments: !this.props.comments.length,
    hasNewComment: false
  }

  handleNewComment = () => {
    // STATE CHANGE UPON FORM SUBMIT IN CHILD
    this.setState({
      hasNewComment: true
    })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    const {comments} = this.props
    const {hasComments, hasNewComment} = this.state
    return (
      <section className="comments">
        <h3>Comments</h3>
        {(hasComments || hasNewComment) ? (
          // list of comments working fine
        ) : (
          // no comments
        )}
        // USING THIS LINE TO PASS DOWN CALLBACK
        <CommentForm newComment={this.handleNewComment} />
      </section>
    )
  }

}

// CHILD

class CommentForm extends React.Component {

 state={...} // nothing to do with the parent

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let url = this.props.apiUrl
    const { newComment } = this.state
    fetch(`${url}/api/comments`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(newComment)
    }).then(() => this.props.newComment()) // CALLBACK TO UPDATE PARENT STATE
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="comment-form">
        ...
      </form>
    )
  }

}
```

I'm hoping the list of comments in the parent Comments to re-render upon the state change, but nothing happens even though the state change is successful.

Comment: where is the logic for adding the new comment to the existing list (so that it changes)?

Comment: Is the problem that hasComments is not being updated? I can't see where you would be updating it. Try making a CodeSandbox.

Comment: How are you sending back the new comments from Child to Parent?

Comment: Instead of using `comments` in the parent state, I'm using `hasNewComment` which is toggled from `false` to `true` by the child when a new comment is added. I've tried using a `comments` as state as suggested but not having any luck either.

Comment: What's the source of Comments List for Your Comments component? You send the POST request in CommentForm but it seems to not update the actual comments list so React compares your old list with new list (which is the same) and doesn't change it.